# Where are all the bottles?

Tags: zelda-link-between-worlds

In Zelda games, bottles are pretty useful and often there are one or two that are well-hidden. I'm a bit surprised in this one that I've only done 3 dungeons of the game and already found 4 bottles.

How many are there, and where can I find them all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The places I've visited suggest that there are 5 bottles in the game:

- **Kakariko Merchant (Hyrule)** - There is a merchant in this village that will sell you a bottle for 100 rupees
- **Under the Bridge (Hyrule)** - With Zora Flippers, there is a stone bridge to the right of Link's house. Talk to the man who lives under the bridge to receive a bottle
- **Message in a Bottle (Hyrule)** - With Zora Flippers, go east of lake Hylia, where you can find an empty bottle. This will give you a quest involving filling the bottle with premium milk from Kakariko village and delivering it to a man who is lost on Death Mountain
- **Vacant House (Lorule)** - Go to Link's house in Lorule and bomb the back of the house. Enter, and find a chest containing a bottle
- **Great Rupee Fairy (Lorule**) - In the Lorule Fairy Fountain, you will find a giant crack near it. Bomb it with the Bomb Flower, and then donate 3,000 rupees to the fairy

Sources:

http://segmentnext.com/2013/11/22/the-legend-of-zelda-a-link-between-worlds-empty-bottles-locations/

http://www.zeldauniverse.net/zelda/albw-bottles/

http://www.zeldainformer.com/walkthrough/page/collectibles-guide

Comment: Looks like you can collect them all pretty early on!

Comment: The answers were very helpful, but are there any more?